# custom sharepoint workflow development using visual studio 2008

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I have a requirement which requires custom workflow development. But as I have never created any workflow programatically before, I dont know how to start with. I have a WSPBuilder installed in visual studio 2008, Can anyone please let me know the steps to develop using wsp builder. I have googled for this but unfortunately i did not find anything regarding this. Also, Please suggest me if using WSP builder is the easiest way of developing workflows or is there any other way of implementing it.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSPBuilder will not help you develop workflow at all. WSPBuilder assists you in building a WSP out of solution files of SharePoint.

To develop workflows, you need to be first aware with Windows workflow Foundation. Start with an example here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627284(v=office.12).aspx

Once you have learnt the basics, and you can build the workflow manually, then you can use WSPBuilder to build the WSP.

In short, WSPBuilder will help you build WSP which is nothing but deployment package such as rpm, deb in linux environment.